# Slow Performing OpenJPA Query

Tags: java, openjpa

I have the following query method that has slow performance:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Long> getFeatureCounts() {

    StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
    timer.start();
    Map<String, Long> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>();  // I want to ensure that the features are in alpha order

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    String jpaQuery = "SELECT F.featureClass, COUNT(DISTINCT F.id) FROM Feature F GROUP BY F.featureClass ORDER BY F.featureClass";
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpaQuery);

    List resultList = query.getResultList();

    for (Object o : resultList) {
        Object[] o2 = (Object[]) o;
        String key = (String) o2[0];
        Long value = (Long) o2[1];
        resultMap.put(key, value);
    }

    em.close();

    timer.stop();
    log.info("getFeatureCounts() executed in " + timer.getTime() + "ms.");

    return resultMap;
}
```

The table has about 1.3M records, but there is an index on featureClass, and F.id is the primary key. I'm waiting results back in something like the following format:

Airport->20316
Bridge->6509
etc.

LinkedHashMap is a requirement so I can maintain the order of the keys (it's either that or call Collections.sort() later... kind of a pay now or pay later thing).

Table definition is below:

CREATE TABLE FEATURE(
    FEATUREID   INTEGER,
    FEATURENAME        VARCHAR(100),
    FEATURECLASS  VARCHAR(100),
    LAT           NUMERIC(14,5),
    LNG           NUMERIC(14,5),
    FEATURESOURCE  VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(FEATUREID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

create index idx_featureclass on FEATURE(FEATURECLASS);

Any help is appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Have you looked at the Execution plan of the query? That will tell you what indexes, seeks/scans you are using

Comment: The `COUNT(DISTINCT F.id)` seems unnecessary. A `COUNT(1)` would give you the same result.

Comment: Have you run the same query as a normal SQL query? Just to make sure that the slowness is only with JPA and not the query as a whole.

Comment: Using COUNT(1) gave me MUCH better performance. There's probably still room for improvement, but that's good enough for now. Kees: if you post as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COUNT(DISTINCT F.id)` seems unnecessary. A `COUNT(1)` would give you the same result. And probably better performance ;-).